# sfdx install fails with: Not available for deploy for this organization

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, install

I've been struggling to debug this all afternoon. Perhaps someone can help?

I've created a managed package using SFDX and everything looks good. I can even promote the package. However when I try to install it (either with the URL or the CLI) the install fails. I've tried both a scratch org and real org.

The package is pretty simple:
- add some custom fields for a standard SF entity
- trigger
- Apex class

Anyone got any clues or debugging tips?

> UPDATE: the install works when I switch the scratch org from
>   "Professional" to "Developer". How do I configure my package so that
>   it will install into a "Professional" org?
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm
>
> This link implies that **only** managed packages that have passed security review (in the AppExchange?) can run in PE orgs.

```
sfdx force:package:install --package "xxxxx@0.1.0-6" --targetusername yyyyyyy --installationkey zzzzz --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --loglevel trace --apiversion 44.0


Waiting for the package install request to complete. Status = IN_PROGRESS
ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 
1) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: TestClause: Not available for deploy for this organization
2) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: ClauseMock: Not available for deploy for this organization
3) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: TestContractInsert: Not available for deploy for this organization
4) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: Clause: Not available for deploy for this organization
5) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: ContractTrigger: Not available for deploy for this organization
ERROR running force:package:install:  Installation errors: 
1) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: TestClause: Not available for deploy for this organization
2) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: ClauseMock: Not available for deploy for this organization
3) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: TestContractInsert: Not available for deploy for this organization
4) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: Clause: Not available for deploy for this organization
5) Not available for deploy for this organization, Details: ContractTrigger: Not available for deploy for this organization
```

Comment: Does the package rely on any features (ex. CPQ)? If so, I'd check your org or scratch org has the enabled features necessary.

Comment: No - it just extends the "Contract" entity.

Comment: What's the User Profile from which you try to install the package? Also, what's your target Org's licence?

Comment: No sure I completely understand, apologies (quite new to this!). I am trying to deploy to a scratch org. which I created from the same DevHub org as the scratch org used to create the package. All users are System Admin AFAIK. I've now hit my 6 (!) deploys per day limit, so will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have `AuthorApex` listed in the `features` for your Professional edition scratch org definition file?

Comment: Are you trying to install this in a production environment? Try this one: sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package "xxxxx@0.1.0-6" -r -u yourOrg